# Can't access the parent for a belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

With the following associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

In rails console after creating an instance of `Comment`, I can access it's associated `Post`:

```
comment = current_user.comments.create(post_id: 2, body: "Sint voluptatem dolor a veniam pariatur")
comment.post # returns it's parent
```

But the same action in the controller, returns `nil`:

```
@comment = current_user.comments.create(comment_params)
@comment.post # => nil
@comment.post_id # => 2
```

The content of `comment_params` is:

```
puts comment_params
=> {"body"=>"Sint voluptatem dolor a veniam pariatur", "post_id"=>"2"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `post` with `id` 2 is present in the database.

Looks like the `post` doesn't exist, which is why it is returning `nil`.